# How to connect to JDBC (Derby DB) from strongloop?

Tags: jdbc, derby, strongloop

I've found that StrongLoop can connect to MongoDB, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and MS SQL Server. 
Can it also connect via JDBC (or Derby DB)?

Seems there are also tutorials to create a customized db connector. Just trying to find out more information there.